# Is there a way to specify port range nmap3 Scan?

Tags: python-3.x, automation

```
import namp3
nmscan = nmap3.NmapScanTechniques()
result = nmscan.nmap_syn_scan("HostIP")
```

This scans all the ports up to 60,000+ but I was wonder if there is a way to specify range on port??
Any help will be very good.
Thank you.

For python3-nmap3 please visit: https://pypi.org/project/python3-nmap/

Answer (score 0):

You can add arguments. In this example, it will scan ports 1 to 100:

```py
import nmap3

target = "45.33.32.156"

nmap = nmap3.NmapScanTechniques()
result = nmap.nmap_tcp_scan(target, args="-p1-100")

print(result)
```